# stack ghci does not load local module but ghci does

Tags: haskell-stack

This is similar to the question at 
[stack ghci not loading up local modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479233/stack-ghci-not-loading-up-local-modules)
but not exactly the same.

I have a directory with the files Main.hs and Shapes.hs where Main.hs has a reference to the module Shapes.

If I run

> ghci Main.hs

everything works fine. This is version 7.10.

But if I run, in version 8,

> stack ghci
>
> :load Main.hs

I get the error

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )
>
> Main.hs:3:1: error:
>
> Failed to load interface for ‘Shapes’
>
> It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

I tried the solution on the link

> :load Shapes.hs Main.hs

but it still does not work. I get the error

> [1 of 2] Compiling Shapes           ( Shapes.hs, interpreted )
>
> [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )
>
> Main.hs:1:1: error:
>
> The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’
>
> Failed, modules loaded: Shapes.

I found the following which discusses this second matter:

[How to avoid "‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’" when using syntastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518927/how-to-avoid-main-is-not-defined-in-module-main-when-using-syntastic/30519208)

But if I were to put in

> main :: IO ()

in the Main.hs file, I still get errors. If I were to additionally add the line

> main = return ()

and have these two additional lines at the end, then it would load. But after loading it just exits main and I no longer have access to the functions in main.
I don't see any reason why I need to use any IO features when I import some other module. How do I, in version 8, load a local module without using IO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. There was a line in Main.hs at the top called

> module Main where

that I removed. Now it works if I load in stack ghci with

> :l Main.hs Shapes.hs